# add values with PHP

Tags: php

I have a database table with two fields both id and value and I'd like to add the two entries for value together and then echo out the total of the sum.

So far I've been able to display both entries for value by using the following.

```
function showTotal() {

global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if (!$result) {

die('Query FAILED' . mysqli_error());


} else if (isset($failed)) {

echo "Failed";

} 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$value = $row['value'];

echo "$value";

            }
                }
```

What I really want is these values added together rather than displaying alongside each other.

Thanks
James

Comment: So sum up the values in your query or do it in PHP. It's easy to do in both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but something like this could potentially be a one-liner.

```
echo array_sum( array_column( mysqli_fetch_all( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC), 'value' ) );
```

That said, if you do not need all the results, this is a better option:

```
$result = mysqli_query( 'SELECT SUM(value) AS mysum FROM table' );
echo mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)['mysum'];
```

Comment: I've tried your first suggestion however the calculation seems to be ignoring the first entry for value and gives me a total of 10 from the two values 1,10.

Comment: ignore me, syntax error, your suggestion works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using php you could sum up the values like so:

```
$value = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $value += $row['value'];

}

echo $value;
```

Comment: I've tried this but I get a result of 111 from the two values 1,10. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 2):

While I personally would opt to go with the solution offered by @jm, PHP does offer another way with its array_sum(), as follows:

```
<?php

$value = 0;

while ($row[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {}

echo array_sum($row['value']);
```

See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Note: you could change the fetching of the result by using mysqli_fetch_all, if you have the MySQL native driver; see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).